# how to make a header like this image with pure css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a  Header as in the picture but only pure Css language and without Photoshop
Is It Possible ??
How do I design it like in the picture in a professional way
[click to see image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKVjo.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple divs.

I tried it with one main container and then you can add the lower nav div with absolute positioning.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    Logo Text
</div>
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="lowerMenu">
  <br>
  Lorem ipsum<br>
  Lorem ipsum<br>
  Lorem ipsum<br>
  Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
```

[See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh4c2zpa/)

Comment: I mean the shape of the header from the bottom like the images